# Changing final build plate position

Tags: g-code, build-plate

I have a Monoprice Maker Select V2 (Wanhao Duplicator i3) on which I've installed a recent version of Marlin.

The home position is at the front-left of the build plate. At the end of the print, the print head returns to this position by moving the build plate *back*.

Can I modify this to return the print head to the back-left corner, so that the print ends with the part more easily accessible?

Here is the default G-code for this printer in Ultimaker Cura:

```
 M104 S0 ;extruder heater off 
 G91 ;relative positioning
 G1 E-1 F300  ;retract the filament a bit before lifting the nozzle, to release some of the pressure
 G1 Z+0.5 E-5 X-20 Y-20 F{speed_travel} ;move Z up a bit and retract filament even more
 G28 X0 Y0 ;move X/Y to min endstops, so the head is out of the way
 M84 ;steppers off
 G90 ;absolute positioning
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe I would want to do:

```
 M104 S0 ;extruder heater off 
 G91 ;relative positioning
 G1 E-1 F300  ;retract the filament a bit before lifting the nozzle, to release some of the pressure
 G1 Z+0.5 E-5 X-20 Y-20 F{speed_travel} ;move Z up a bit and retract filament even more
 G90 ;absolute positioning
 G0 X0 Y200 ; move to back-left corner
 M84 ;steppers off
```

Here, `Y200` is the depth of my build plate.

This works, but the movement is very slow.

Comment: That approach is correct. You'd normally still use `G1` commands for non-extrusion moves these days. Use `Fxxx` to provide a speed for that last movement, for example `F6000` for 100 mm/s - it's unfortunately still in mm/min.